# Facebook send dialog box not able to send message

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, send, facebook-fbml

I am getting an error every time when I try to send link with send dialog box, please any one help me out.
Error Detail: - "Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can."

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error, and I think it happened to me because I was using links that are not accessible publicly.  Try sending "www.google.com" as the link parameter and see if it still happens.